# Why does my form freeze when using an array that reads from a text file?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, filereader

All syntax is correct and no errors appear when i run the code, but when i click the login button on the form, it just freezes, i think it's due to the array.
Here is the code below. Im not sure how to make it efficient to make it not freeze.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form3

    Dim reader1 As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim classdata As Array
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        reader1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\ryanm_000\Documents\username and password.txt")
        While reader1.EndOfStream = True
            classdata = reader1.ReadLine.Split(",")
            If TextBox1.Text = "admin" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "iamtheboss" Then
                MsgBox("Welcome Mr Khan", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Admin")
                Me.Hide()
                My.Forms.Form7.Text = Now.ToString
                My.Forms.Form7.Show()

            ElseIf TextBox1.Text = classdata(0) AndAlso TextBox2.Text = classdata(1) Then
                Me.Hide()
                My.Forms.Form5.Text = Now.ToString
                My.Forms.Form5.Show()
                reader1.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("Sorry, username or password is invalid, please try again", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")

            End If
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Visual Studio comes with an excellent tool called a *debugger* so you can find and fix this kind of problem.  `All syntax is correct and no errors appear` just means it compiles, it doesnt mean there are no bugs

Comment: You're looping While EndOfStream = True.  That seems illoicial.  If the file is empty it will loop forever because it's always the end of the stream.  If the file is not empty, it will be false and never enter the loop.(Basically, phaon's answer which he added while I was thinking about this)

Comment: The problem is certainly not the array. Debug your code! Set a breakpoint on the first statement of the method and execute it line by line and you will see why it does not work! See: [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: [Obligatory](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to process the file while your reader is not at the end of the stream.
Try changing your while condition to `While reader1.EndofStream = False` or (better) you could write `While Not reader1.EndOfStream`